# Getting live/current version of .app or .ipa

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

Does anyone know where I can get the live version (1.5) .app or .ipa file? I need to symbolicate a crash report, but I am currently developing the next version (1.6) of the app so I don't have the (1.5 version) .app or .ipa file on my local machine!!!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you download from the AppStore?

You could export the .ipa from the Organizer. When you archived the version to Submit to the AppStore, a register on the Organizer is created with the date and status Submitted.

For the future, I recommend you using git and creating a branch everytime you release a version.

Comment: Oh, you mean download it in iTunes, not on the iPhone (good idea!) The register for that version is no longer in Organizer. Yeah, I have a backup zip of that version which Im trying now. (I'm slowly moving to git)

Thank you!

Comment: I can download the .ipa, but i still need the .dSYM

Answer (score 1):

You will need the dSYM in order to symbolicate. The dSYM is different with each build. If you do not have the original build, there is no way to do this.

So even when you use git, remember to check in the xcarchive (or the dSYM) in the future.

Comment: Yeah, I had to submit a new version. I am now saving the xcarchive with each release, Thank you ;-)